# How to store an id of user with google analytics api?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I want to use google analytics in my android app to know which users are using my app and how frequently are they using the app.

For this I implemented the google sdk. But now, I can not properly see which user is using the app and how frequently.

Report shows like this :

[image]

[image]

But it dose not show the active user though the screen is on.

code:

```
      // Make sure global_tracker.xml is configured
        if (!checkConfiguration()) {
            View contentView = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            Snackbar.make(contentView, "bad config", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
        }

        // [START shared_tracker]
        // Obtain the shared Tracker instance.
        AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
        // [END shared_tracker]


        sendScreenImageName();

private void sendScreenImageName() {

        // [START screen_view_hit]

        //  mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + getLocalClassName());
        mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + preferences.getString("acno",""));
        mTracker.setAppVersion(getString(R.string.appVersion));
        mTracker.set("User",preferences.getString("acno",""));

        // mTracker.setClientId(preferences.getString("acno",""));
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());

        mTracker.setAppInstallerId(preferences.getString("acno",""));

        // [END screen_view_hit]
    }

    /**
     * Check to make sure global_tracker.xml was configured correctly (this function only needed
     * for sample apps).
     */
    private boolean checkConfiguration() {
        XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.global_tracker);

        boolean foundTag = false;
        try {
            while (parser.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (parser.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG) {
                    String tagName = parser.getName();
                    String nameAttr = parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");

                    foundTag = "string".equals(tagName) && "ga_trackingId".equals(nameAttr);
                }

                if (parser.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.TEXT) {
                    if (foundTag && parser.getText().contains("UA-112531272-1")) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                parser.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("config", "checkConfiguration", e);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

global_tracker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="UA-112531272-1" translatable="false">""</string>
</resources>
```

I want to send an id of user with session and check id wise usage on analytics site.

Also the tracking is not proper sometimes it gets track and sometimes it dose not is anything wrong in code?

How to do that?

Can anyone help please? Thank you.

Comment: Hmm, that may be against Google's License agreement, cause you will basically track every individual, with knowledge who the person is.

Comment: isnt it possible? also the tracking is not proper sometimes it gets track and sometimes it dose not is anything wrong in code? @Anuga

Comment: Recommendation use Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Since this isn't allowed by Google's License agreement you can work around it [encrypting a PII and saving it on a custom dimension](http://dmitriilin.com/encrypt-personally-identifiable-information-using-google-tag-manager/) (This is allowed but you need at least a SHA-256).

Maybe this doesnt help a lot but i ll strongly advise you to use Firebase + GTM + GA.

Comment: Can you please provive some links how to implement Firebase + GTM + GA.? and is it for android too?

Comment: Yes it works on android too but i cant advice you much since i did it on iOS. Here are some links: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/  https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es-419

Comment: @Sid One of the advantages of this is you can manipulate the data from Google Tag Manager at any time without needing to publish a new update. If is there anything else i can help don't hesitate on asking.